# Got a "player" class with a virtual class inside, can't save a new player because of the virtual class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I've got three classes. In my Create view I got a dropdownlist that loads all the FootballTeam's.
But the problem is when I post to the controller. Because the ModelState.IsValid isn't valid. I know it is something with the "public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeam { get; set; }" because it worked before i added that one :)

The only thing I want to do is to bind a player to a fotballs team. I can change my "public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeam" to an int instead of virtual FootballTeam and that should probably work.
But I saw on this [Entity Framework one to many](http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/27/entity-framework-with-many-to-many-one-to-many-and-one-to-one-relationships/) that it was the best way to map it as I did with virtual FootballTeam.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePlayer(PlayerViewModel playerViewModel)
    {
        var team = db.FootballTeam.Find(playerViewModel.Player.FootballTeam.Id);
        playerViewModel.Player.FootballTeam = team;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Player.Add(playerViewModel.Player);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Teams");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Teams");
    }


@model test.Models.PlayerViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Player.FootballTeam.Id, Model.FootballTeams.Select(y => new SelectListItem
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            Text = y.Name,
                                                                                            Value = y.Id.ToString()
                                                                                        }))

    public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange ett namn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange en possition")]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange födelseåret")]
    public string BirthYear { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange en längd")]
    public string Length { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange en vikt")]
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange moderklubben, alt ett '-'")]
    public string FirstClub { get; set; }
    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeam { get; set; }
}

    public class FootballTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange ett namn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Coach> Coaches { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen fyll i information om laget")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Information { get; set; }
}

    public class PlayerViewModel
{
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Image { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FootballTeam> FootballTeams { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What do you find if you look in the modelstate for errors?